# Copying a gray image the first channel of a type Mat_<Vec2f>

Tags: opencv

I have gotten so far to understand that `merge()` is an option to copy specific channels from a source to destination, but i cannot seem to fully understand how to implement this.

My sample code:

```
Mat_<float> my_grayscale_image = load_image(some_image, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat_<Vec2f> my_grayscale_2chan;
```

So basically i want to copy the gray image `my_grayscale_image` into the first channel of the new 2-channel image `my_grayscale_2chan`.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::merge` is used to join several Mat objects into a single Mat e.g. you can compose `Mat_<Vec2f>` from 2 `Mat_<float>`

```
Mat_<float> first, second;
Mat_<Vec2f> result;
Mat tmp[] = { first, second };
merge(tmp, sizeof(tmp)/sizeof(Mat), result);
```

To copy a channel into existing Mat object you can use universal [mixChannels](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels) function. Or there is an undocumented shorthand for your case:

```
//void cv::insertChannel(InputArray _src, InputOutputArray _dst, int coi)
insertChannel(my_grayscale_image, my_grayscale_2chan, 0);
```

Comment: I tried the first example but instead of having first and second in temp i only have first. This failed `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (CV_MAT_TYPE(mtype) == m.type()) in create`

Comment: Furthermore how do i ensure that the grayscale image is copied into the first channel of my result vector?

Comment: @JavaCake You need both first and second and they will both be your initial image. E.g. Mat tmp[] = {my_grayscale_image, my_grayscale_image};

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following...

```
cvMerge(my_grayscale_image,NULL,NULL,NULL,my_grayscale_2chan)..
```

Comment: `OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat`

Comment: It says i cant cast from Mat_<float> to CvArr